# Transforming Vertices Using the Transformation Matrix of Bones

Tags: java, animation, matrix, lwjgl, skeletal-animation

Hey guys so recently I have been trying to wrap my head around 3-D skeletal animation and I am very confused.  First of all, I do not under stand what offsets are used for and what they are and secondly (I am not sure if it related to offsets) But if a bone has a transformation matrix, how would it work when the bone's joint is not the origin.  Transformation matrices use an origin as a pivot point I understand and the pivot point must the joint which may or may not be the origin.  Thanks!